# Low-resolution image when drawing text using System.Drawing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, system.drawing

I am trying to write an image onto a PDF using iTextSharp, but aside from the images being written I also need to add text to the PDF.  It seems like the best way to do this has been to write the text as an image and insert it onto the page.  That all works fine, but when I take a look at the text I see that it is lower quality than I'd like.  I end up getting something like this:

[image]

You can see there are a lot of "dots" that are different from the surrounding solid background.  Here is the code I am using to draw the text:

```
private System.Drawing.Image DrawText(String text, System.Drawing.Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

        img.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        img = new Bitmap((int) textSize.Width, (int) textSize.Height);
        //img.SetResolution(200, 200);

        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        drawing.Clear(backColor);

        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

        drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);
        //drawing.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        //drawing.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        //drawing.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        //img.MakeTransparent(Color.MediumAquamarine);

        drawing.Save();

        textBrush.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        return img;
    }
```

and the relevant text from the PDF writer:

```
    var name = DrawText(Request.Form["name"], font, Color.Black, Color.White);
    ...
    Image titleImg = Image.GetInstance(title.ToStream(ImageFormat.Jpeg));
    titleImg.SetAbsolutePosition(float.Parse(Request.Form["x"]), float.Parse(Request.Form["y"]));
    titleImg.ScaleToFit(16, 16);           
    pdfContentByte.AddImage(titleImg);
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the iTextSharp `ScaleToFit()` or the drawing method, but I'd like to clean up the background color a bit.  You can see the various methods I've tried commented out of the `DrawText()` method.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't draw the text as bitmap in the first place, I'd use PDF text showing operators allowing arbitrary smoothness of the writing.

Comment: @mkl what do you mean?  Do you have an example of a way to use what you mentioned above?  When I tried to add text to the PDF it didn't work out as well as I would have hoped...it just created new pages instead of appending where I needed it to, which are basically tokens within the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TextRenderingHint` and `SmoothingMode` values you tried are actually counter-productive.

If you don't want antialiasing pixels whirling around the text turn them off! 
Setting the `TextRenderingHint`to `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit` or `SingleBitPerPixel` should work better.

**But** even with `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` the pixelation certainly wouldn't be so strong if you didn't **save as** `jpeg`, **which is probably the only real mistake**.

Whenever **text** is involved **do not use** `jpeg`, which is strictly for photographs **but use** `png`!

So **first** change

```
Image titleImg = Image.GetInstance(title.ToStream(ImageFormat.Jpeg));
```

to

```
Image titleImg = Image.GetInstance(title.ToStream(ImageFormat.Png));
```

and **only then** check if you still want to optimze the `TextRenderingHint`!

**Note** that this answer is strictly about getting rid of the artifacts around your text.

The best and fully scaleable way to enter text into a `PFD` document is to enter real text, not bitmaps, just as mkl has commented. How to do that with `ITextSharp` and in the context of your application is a good, new question you may want to post. (Include your failing efforts and an image of the desired result..!)

Comment: changing it from jpeg to png did the trick; I didn't have to change the `TextRenderingHint` at all.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I used your code, and it comes out pretty nice.

I cleaned up the method that broke it into two (2) separate methods, then I started with a larger Bitmap (not 1x1):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class Program
{

    public static Color COLOR_TEXT = Color.Red;
    public static Color COLOR_BACK = Color.White;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 35);
        var image = DrawClass.DrawText2("Stack Overflow\r\n\tby jp2code", font, COLOR_TEXT, COLOR_BACK);
        image.Save("C:\\jp2code.bmp");
    }

    public static Image DrawText2(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
    {
        var textSize = GetTextSize(text, font);
        var result = new Bitmap((int)textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.Clear(backColor);
            var brush = new SolidBrush(textColor);
            g.DrawString(text, font, brush, 0, 0);
            g.Save();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static SizeF GetTextSize(String text, Font font)
    {
        using (var img = new Bitmap(200, 100))
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
            {
                return g.MeasureString(text, font);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my output file:

[image: screenshot]

Pretty cool. That was my reasoning for giving you that upvote a few hours ago.